# Find an element by its class attribute in DOM with raw javascript without using ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Ok. Suddenly I have this query in my mind.

Libraries like **jQuery** makes it real easy to look for an element having some `class`. It does not force us to apply an `id` on the element to be found. In Vanilla js we have the option to find out an element using the method `getElementById()` which forces me to apply IDs to a large extent.

I looked at this [solution](http://snipplr.com/view/1853/get-elements-by-attribute/) to find an element using an attribute which in this case is going to be `class`. After going through the solutions I find it very heavy on the browser. If I have a complex DOM structure, it will cost performance. And my question remains the same.

How do I find an element using `class name` and without using `id` in Vanilla Javascript?

Comment: strikes me as a reasonable question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass');
```

That will return a set of elements which have the given class. You could then access them using `elems[0]` , `elems[1]` and so on..

Remember that jQuery is ultimately based on JavaScript, so it can't be faster from an execution point of view.

You might find some interesting jQuery to JavaScript translations here

http://vanilla-js.com/

For older versions of IE you need to use `getElementsByTagName` and loop over the returned elements. This utility function should be [compatible from IE6 onwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName#Browser_Compatibility) (probably similar to the solution you linked to)

```
function getElementsByAttributeValue(atrName,atrValue) {
    var matchElems = [];

    var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var x = 0, len = allElems.length; x < len; x++) {
        if(allElems[x].getAttribute(atrName) != atrValue) {
            continue;
        }

        matchElems.push(allElems[x]);
    }

    return matchElems;
}
```

Usage would be:

```
var elems = getElementsByAttributeValue("class","someclass");
```

Comment: You could also look into the http://sizzlejs.com/ library. It is the same that jquery uses.

Comment: although i accepted your answer, the problem with `getElementsByClassName()` is it does not work with IE8. I want this to be crossbrowser and supporting IE's older versions is critical to the project.

Comment: @pjp answer has been updated with possible solution for older versions of IE6

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByClassName('testclass');` will give you the element with the testclass, You could also use `document.getElementsByTagName('img');` this will give you the img elements.